# screen problem with 12.04 Install on a HP dv9000

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, hp-pavilion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I installed 12.04 on a HP dv9000 laptop. I first tried to install with a Windows partition; then tried to install and move files from windows but not have a dual boot; then tried to install and have 12.04 have the system all to itself. The install was done off a burned CD... All went well.

On reboot - it takes a while to come up to the user ID and password challenge. After providing input, screen renders and then turns black.

First time Ubuntu user/installer - not technical :-)... Thanks for any help... I'll keep on digging in parallel.